# Codeigniter incorrect CAPTCHA image src

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hi I am trying to use the CodeIgniter captcha helper for my registration page .
I have an User controller with register function like below :

```
public function register(){   
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name' , 'Username' , 'trim|required|max_length[32]'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha' , 'Captcha' , 'trim|required|max_length[32]|callback_check_captcha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password','trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', 'Confirm Password','trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|matches[password]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
    //Captcha code 
    $this->load->helper('captcha');
    //Captcha Config 
    $vals = array(
        'img_path'      => './captcha/',
        'img_url'       => './captcha/',
        'img_width'     => '150',
        'img_height'    => 30,
        'expiration'    => 7200,
        'word_length'   => 8,
        'font_size'     => 16,
        'img_id'        => 'Imageid',
         'font_path'     => '/fonts/Open.ttf',

        // White background and border, black text and red grid
        'colors'        => array(
                'background' => array(255, 255, 255),
                'border' => array(255, 255, 255),
                'text' => array(0, 0, 0),
                'grid' => array(255, 40, 40)
        )
    );
    //Create the Captcha
    $cap = create_captcha($vals);

    // Store The Created Captcha in DB for Verification  
    $data = array(
    'captcha_time'  => $cap['time'],
    'ip_address'    => $this->input->ip_address(),
    'word'          => $cap['word']
    );
    $this->register_model->store_captcha($data);
    //Load View
    $data['image']=$cap['image'];
    var_dump($data['image']);exit();
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('register' , $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }else {
              $option=array('cost'=>12);
              $encrypt_password=password_hash($this->input->post('password'),PASSWORD_BCRYPT,$option);
              $this->register_model->add_user($encrypt_password);
              $this->session->set_flashdata('user_registered','You are Successfully Registered and can Log in ');
              redirect('register/success');
    }
}
```

If you see the above code I am setting the 'img_path' to './captcha/'(using the root relative method) . I have this folder captcha in the root .

In my view I have  :

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Enter UserID</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name"  placeholder="Enter Your UserId">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Enter Your Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"  placeholder="Enter Your Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Enter Your Password </label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"  placeholder="Enter Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
        <label>Re-enter Password </label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password"  placeholder="Renter Password">
  </div>
  <?php echo $image ; ?>
  <div class="form-group">
        <label>Solve Captcha </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" >
  </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  <?php echo form_close();?>
```

The problem is my image is not showing up . When inspected the captcha image  I  found it to be correct like below :

```
<img id="Imageid" src="./captcha/1551023447.5228.jpg" style="width: 150; height: 30; border: 0;" alt=" ">
```

However , the src is actually getting 'computed' to : http://[::1]/login/user/captcha/1551023447.5228.jpg . See the image below .

[image: computed src]

Could somebody tell me why the src is pointing to http://[::1]/login/user/captcha/1551023447.5228.jpg  all though  it should be http://[::1]/login/captcha/1551023447.5228.jpg   ? I am also curious to know how hovering over the  img src in chrome shows a different value than what is actually in the code . I understand /.path is used to traverse folders from the root but this is the first time I am seeing something like this in chrome . Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path params looks not right. It should be full URL of the captcha directory like

```
$vals = array(
    'img_path'      => 'captcha/',
    'img_url'       => base_url('captcha')
.....
```

Assuming that you have a `captcha` directory in your project root, also you enabled `url` helper in `config/autoload.php`

About chrome dev tool path, Its calculate the relative path the display full URL so that you can go there by click.